# Emmeans produce negative values for prob 95%CI for multinomial regression

Tags: confidence-interval, multinomial-distribution, lsmeans, nnet

I'm fitting a multinomial logistic regression and I'm getting two issues:

```
  library(emmeans)
  library(nnet)
  library(multcomp)
  DF = data.frame(IND = c(rep("A",5),rep("B",11),rep("C",4),
            rep("A",3),rep("B",5),rep("C",2)),
            G = c(rep("G1",20),rep("G2",10)))
  table(DF)
  MULTI = multinom(IND ~ G, data = DF);summary(MULTI)
  EMMEANS = emmeans(MULTI,~G*IND, mode = "prob");EMMEANS
  PAIR = pairs(EMMEANS, type = "response", adjust="tukey");PAIR
  CLD = cld(EMMEANS, alpha=0.05, Letters=letters,adjust="tukey");CLD
```

1 - Why are `emmeans` and `cld` reporting negative values for `lower.CL`, even if I used `mode = "prob"`? Can I convert them to zero?

2 - Why `pairs` does not return `odds.ratio`, even if I used `ratio = T`? If I use `exp(estimate)` do I get `odds.ratio`?

Thank you all in advance!

Comment: This happens because when there isn't much data, and some of the estimated probabilities are small. It's possible ifor the SEs to be big enough to mske the CI endpoints go negative. CLD is just a data frame so you can nanipulate the negative limits to be changed to 0. Or get more data?

Comment: Dear Prof. Lenth, thank you so much for your reply. Unfortunately, I cannot get more data, so I'll have to convert the negative values to zero. Best regards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not unusual at all to get negative confidence limits with small datasets. They are due to using naive normal-theory intervals: $\hat p \pm z_{\alpha/2}SE(\hat p)$. When $\hat p$ is small and the sample size is small, the $\pm$ part can easily exceed $\hat p$, leading to a negative bound.

There is kind of a workaround for this. The `"prob"` mode involves considerable post-processing, so by the time we get to the estimates themselves, it is way too late. However, the `transform` argument is passed to the reference grid right after it is constructed, along with auxiliary arguments such as `N.sim`. So we can get the software to simulate values from the sampling distribution on the linear-predictor scale; then those simulations are used henceforth as if they were samples from a posterior distribution. This does a much better job of keeping us in bounds:

```
> (emm2 = emmeans(MULTI,~G*IND, mode = "prob", 
                  transform = "pass", N.sim = 1000))

Generating a posterior sample of size 1000
 G  IND  prob lower.HPD upper.HPD
 G1 A   0.251    0.0724     0.455
 G2 A   0.303    0.0298     0.578
 G1 B   0.549    0.3216     0.763
 G2 B   0.487    0.1979     0.812
 G1 C   0.203    0.0181     0.378
 G2 C   0.197   -0.0156     0.465

Point estimate displayed: median 
HPD interval probability: 0.95 

> pairs(emm2)
 contrast    estimate lower.HPD upper.HPD
 G1 A - G2 A -0.05611  -0.36235    0.2973
 G1 A - G1 B -0.29662  -0.66566    0.0561
 G1 A - G2 B -0.24502  -0.60983    0.1033
 G1 A - G1 C  0.04915  -0.23211    0.3643
 G1 A - G2 C  0.04872  -0.25559    0.3496
 G2 A - G1 B -0.24292  -0.59601    0.1025
 G2 A - G2 B -0.18666  -0.69630    0.3710
 G2 A - G1 C  0.10710  -0.19314    0.4655
 G2 A - G2 C  0.10372  -0.32463    0.4908
 G1 B - G2 B  0.06313  -0.32163    0.4363
 G1 B - G1 C  0.35135   0.00661    0.7039
 G1 B - G2 C  0.35400   0.03511    0.6642
 G2 B - G1 C  0.29695  -0.03502    0.6413
 G2 B - G2 C  0.29292  -0.21142    0.7314
 G1 C - G2 C  0.00192  -0.28734    0.2834

Point estimate displayed: median 
HPD interval probability: 0.95
```

Note that this produces a Bayesian-like summary based on highest posterior density regions. It didn't keep all the limits from going negative, but they are a lot better behaved. (You can do `summary(emm2, point.est = mean)` if you would rather see means instead of medians; it will not change the intervals.)

You can't use `cld()` on these results, but that's a method I recommend against anyway.

#### Postscript

I was surprised to see any negative values at all, so I traced this and found out that the simulations not done early as I had thought, but are done on the final results on the `"prob"` scale. They still behave a lot better, probably because the covariances among the estimated $\hat p$ values are taken into account. I will investigate why it didn't work at the linear-predictor level as I had described.

#### Postscript 2

Adding `transform = "response", N.sim = ...` *does* already work
correctly for ordinal models, just not for `multinom` because it turns out
this doesn't use `regrid()` until later. I souped-up
the `multinom` support so this does also work for `multinom`
(the `transform` option is not necessary.)

```
> emmeans(MULTI,~G*IND, mode = "prob", N.sim = 1000)
Simulating a sample of size 1000
 G  IND  prob lower.HPD upper.HPD
 G1 A   0.247    0.0888     0.437
 G2 A   0.296    0.0845     0.572
 G1 B   0.535    0.3251     0.742
 G2 B   0.477    0.2196     0.779
 G1 C   0.197    0.0684     0.415
 G2 C   0.183    0.0227     0.456

Point estimate displayed: median 
HPD interval probability: 0.95
```

You need to install this from GitHub or wait until this is updated on CRAN (probably version 1.5.1)

Comment: Dear Professor Lenth, thank you so very much for your very detailed explanation. I would like to ask just one more question. You said that we can't use the `cld` function. Is this impossibility of use due to a numerical incompatibility between the two functions (i.e. the calculations are wrong), or due to a philosophical incompatibility (i.e. the results lead to a wrong interpretation)? Does function `pairs` suffers from this same issue?

Comment: pairs() works because it obtains the pairwise differences of the simulations. But cld() is strictly a frequentist method. It requires P values which we don't have. As I said, I don't recommend cld anyway because it highlights NON-findings rather than findings. Two means not being significantly different is a non-finding because we didn't prove they are the same, we only failed to prove them different. So when we group things according to what we aren't able to show, that's confusing if not downright misleading.

Comment: Now I totally understand, prof. Lenth. Thank you very much again!